# Hacer una media con MySQL y CASE WHEN o WHERE crea differencia

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo los siguientes campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 3965 Corona    USA California 124966
 3973 Concord   USA California 121780
 4054 Fairfield USA California 92256
```

Me gustaria obtener el average de la population de los ciudades que esta en California

Entonces intenté:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE WHEN DISTRICT = 'California' THEN Population ELSE 0 END) FROM CITY
```

Y me devuelve:

```
37666.8889
```

Pero con en siguiente funciona bien

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(CAST(POPULATION AS FLOAT)),3) FROM CITY WHERE DISTRICT = 'CALIFORNIA'
```

Me pregunto por qué hay tanta diferencia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podemos definir el promedio de un conjunto de valores como la suma de los valores dividido la cuenta de los valores:

```
avg(x) = sum(x)/count(x)
```

Con esto en mente, la primera sentencia hace la siguiente operación:

```
     pupulation
         124966
         121780
              0
       --------
sum      246746
count         3

avg = 24676/3 = 82248.666666
```

La segunda, en cambio, hace:

```
     pupulation
         124966
         121780
       --------
sum      246746
count         2

avg = 24676/3 = 123373
```

Es evidente que no has incluido todos los datos o son distintos de los que usas cuando obtienes el valor que pones en la pregunta.

Dado que estas funciones excluyen los valores nulos, podrías obtener el valor correcto de la primera sentencia si omites el `else` de la sentencia case, o si devuelves `null` en lugar de `0`

Answer (score 1):

Traducido del manual:

> A menos que se indique lo contrario, las funciones de agregación ignoran valores `NULL`.

De tal manera que un cero, no afecta la suma, pero sí el conteo para el promedio. En tal caso, deberías entonces usar `NULL`.
Por otro lado, cuando haces un `CASE` de un sólo caso, mejor usa `IF`:

```
SELECT AVG(IF(DISTRICT = 'California', Population, null) FROM CITY
```

Comment: ¿Por qué es mejor usar `if` que `case`?

Comment: @jachguate: No por mucho: Menos verboso con una micro-optimización. Por el contrario, ante `IF`s anidados son más eficientes los `CASE`.

Comment: Y `case` tiene la gran ventaja de ser estándar. Quizás esta sentencia nunca se ejecute en otro motor... pero el programador podría mañana estar en Oracle y la siguiente semana en SQL Server, para luego ir a PosgreSQL y terminar el año con Firebird, y _quizás alguno de esos_ no tenga `if`. Porque realmente pienso que  `case` es _mejor_ por lo ya dicho,  ya que aseveras que **es mejor usar `if`**, pido evidencia de lo que aseveras.